# I want to remove the Chapter name from the header and put Page number on the footer of a Latex file

Tags: header-footer

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}


\usepackage{threeparttable}


\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{makecell}


\long\def\comment#1{}

% uncomment if don't want page numbers
%\pagestyle{empty}

%set dimensions of columns, gap between columns, and paragraph indent 
\setlength{\textheight}{8.75in}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.375in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.8in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0625in}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.1in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.19in}
\setlength{\parindent}{20pt} %{20pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.00in}
\makeatletter
\def\@normalsize{\@setsize\normalsize{10pt}\xpt\@xpt
\abovedisplayskip 10pt plus2pt minus5pt\belowdisplayskip 
\abovedisplayskip \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ 
plus3pt\belowdisplayshortskip 6pt plus3pt 
minus3pt\let\@listi\@listI}

%need an 11 pt font size for subsection and abstract headings 
\def\subsize{\@setsize\subsize{12pt}\xipt\@xipt}
%make section titles bold and 12 point, 2 blank lines before, 1 after
\def\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}{1.0ex plus
1ex minus .2ex}{.2ex plus .2ex}{\large\bf}}
%make subsection titles bold and 11 point, 1 blank line before, 1 after
\def\subsection{\@startsection 
   {subsection}{2}{\z@}{.2ex plus 1ex} {.2ex plus .2ex}{\subsize\bf}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}



\begin{document}

\chapter{This header needs to be deleted and also the page number}.\label{ch:miningAlgorithms}

\newpage
..
..
..
..\newline

\textcolor{blue}{}
..\newline
..\newline
\end{document}
```

The code shows the below output from where I want to delete the header part. Also, want to put the page number at the footer.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! If you want no header, and only the page number in the footer, use `\pagestyle{plain}`.

Comment: Not needed. Just remove `\pagestyle{headings}`. BTW this is a working example, but not minimal. Making a true MWE help even to yourself to identify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Being a GOM it would help if you made up your mind what you wanted. The following MWE, I think, does what your latest thoughts desire.

```
% pagestyleprob.tex SE 604731

\documentclass[onecolumn,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{threeparttable}


\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{makecell}


\long\def\comment#1{}

% uncomment if don't want page numbers
%\pagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{plain}

%set dimensions of columns, gap between columns, and paragraph indent 
\setlength{\textheight}{8.75in}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.375in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.8in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0625in}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.1in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.19in}
\setlength{\parindent}{20pt} %{20pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.00in}
\makeatletter
\def\@normalsize{\@setsize\normalsize{10pt}\xpt\@xpt
\abovedisplayskip 10pt plus2pt minus5pt\belowdisplayskip 
\abovedisplayskip \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ 
plus3pt\belowdisplayshortskip 6pt plus3pt 
minus3pt\let\@listi\@listI}

%need an 11 pt font size for subsection and abstract headings 
\def\subsize{\@setsize\subsize{12pt}\xipt\@xipt}
%make section titles bold and 12 point, 2 blank lines before, 1 after
\def\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}{1.0ex plus
1ex minus .2ex}{.2ex plus .2ex}{\large\bf}}
%make subsection titles bold and 11 point, 1 blank line before, 1 after
\def\subsection{\@startsection 
   {subsection}{2}{\z@}{.2ex plus 1ex} {.2ex plus .2ex}{\subsize\bf}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}
\pagestyle{plain}
%\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\chapter{This header needs to be deleted and also the page number}.\label{ch:miningAlgorithms}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\lipsum[1-10]
\newpage
..
..
..
..\newline

\textcolor{blue}{}
..\newline
..\newline
\end{document}
```